# loopback Rest API to graph data

Tags: graph, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have to create a Rest API to a directional graph model using strongloop loopback. 
I have a collection of nodes and a collection of relationships relating the nodes.
The relationship collection stores the nm relations.

In the models/node.json I have included the following relations

```
  "relations": {
    "incomingNodes": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "node",
      "through": "relationship",
      "foreignKey": "endNode"
    },
    "outgoingNodes": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "node",
      "through": "relationship",
      "foreignKey": "startNode"
    }
}
```

In the models/relationships.json:

```
  "relations": {
    "startNode": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "node",
      "foreignKey": "nodeId"
    },
  "endNode": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "node",
       "foreignKey": "nodeId"
    }
  }
```

The explorer is populated as expected, but if I create a relation using the Rest API

```
/nodes/{id}/incomingNodes/rel/{fk}
```

and look into the database, things are getting weird. 
The following data is written:

```
{
  "id": "55ff1072b88c93a82ae527ea", <--id of the new relationship
  "nodeId": "55fef9a156468fe629d94ac8" <-- id of the {fk}
}
```

I would expect that something like this:

```
{
  "id": "55ff1072b88c93a82ae527ea", <--id of the new relationship
  "startNode": "55fef9a156468fe629d94ac8", <-- id of the {fk}
  "endNode": "55fef9a156468fe629d94ac8" <-- id of the {id}

}
```

I've tried all kinds of combinations, but just can't get it working.

Please help

Comment: Foreign keys in relationships.json are incorrect. Try same keys as in node.json.  "foreignKey": "startNode" and "foreignKey": "endNode" instead of  "foreignKey": "nodeId".

Comment: I've tried that one. :-(  , Finally I've decided to give up, and implement the logic in code using remote methods. I think that the problem is that I have 2 directed relations pointing from the same model to the same model.

Comment: It would be an improvement if I could control the relations a bit more in stead of relying on "magic". By this I mean that you have the possibility to configure the FK explicit. In my case:  Node.id <-> Relationship.startId (trough) Relationship.endId <-> Node.Id   .

Answer (score 0):

A [HasManyThrough relation](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/HasManyThrough+relations) needs 2 things:

- `foreignKey` to identify the origin (model declaring the relation) **in the `through` model**,
- `keyThrough` to identify the target of the relation **in the `through` model**.

A [BelongsTo relation](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/BelongsTo+relations) needs the key to use **in the model declaring the relation** to identify the target.

Now, assuming the following schemas

```
Node (id)
Relationships (id, startNodeId, endNodeId)
```

you need to add `keyThrough` in models/node.json relations:

```
"relations": {
  "incomingNodes": {
    "type": "hasMany",
    "model": "node",
    "through": "relationship",
    "foreignKey": "endNodeId",
    "keyThrough": "startNodeId"
  },
  "outgoingNodes": {
    "type": "hasMany",
    "model": "node",
    "through": "relationship",
    "foreignKey": "startNodeId",
    "keyThrough": "endNodeId"
  }
```

and use `startNodeId` and `endNodeId` in models/relationships.json:

```
"relations": {
  "startNode": {
    "type": "belongsTo",
    "model": "node",
    "foreignKey": "startNodeId"
  },
  "endNode": {
    "type": "belongsTo",
    "model": "node",
    "foreignKey": "endNodeId"
  }
}
```

Note that i used `endNodeId` and `startNodeId` for property names to preserve your relations names in relationships.json, since you can't have both a relation and a property using the same name in a model.